# fast-report show pagefooter when number of rows greater than 32

Tags: delphi, report, fastreport

I have a FastReport data. I want to show the PageFooter only when the number of rows is greater than 32 and hide it if less than 32 rows.

I want a FastReport tips or by Delphi code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tryed so far?

Comment: What do you mean: number of rows per page or number of rows for whole report?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

It is possible to change the text of a system memo instead of showing (hiding) page footer band. Put a SystemMemo object on PageFooter band and use OnBeforePrint event of this system memo. This example works for showing page footer band for rows per page.

**Code:**

```
procedure SysMemo1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
   if COUNT(MasterData1) >= 32 then begin
      SysMemo1.Text := '[Page#]';
      end
   else begin
      SysMemo1.Text := '';                                  
   end;                 
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may change visibility of PageHeader in the main procedure of report script only:

```
begin
    PageHeader1.Visible := MasterData1.DataSet.RecordCount > 32;                                                                                                                          
end.
```